# Django Rest Framework change admin form

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I want to change forms of admin page of DRF.
below link shows how it can change the form.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

But the sample can affect only Django, not DRF?
How can I change the DRF admin page form?

Comment: There is no DRF admin page (by default), exactly what view/admin/form are you talking about?

Comment: I use a custom user model in DRF.
but I can not change the password on the user admin page. @IainShelvington